# Using Plot3D with one variable dependent on the other

Tags: plotting

```
Plot3D[f,{x,xmin,xmax},{y,ymin,ymax}]
```

In the above , is there any way to give range of y in terms of x. I want to give like `{x, 0, 9000}` and `{y, x, 9020-x}` and `f = 9020/(9020 + y)`.

Comment: Also look up `RegionPlot3D`

Comment: Yes f is a function of y and y is dependent on x .

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Plot3D[9020/(9020 + y), {x, 0, 9000}, {y, x, 9020 - x}]
```

[image]

to create the data points explicitly

```
res = Table[{val, #, 9020/(9020 + #)} & /@ (If[val < 9020 - val, 
  Range[val, 9020 - val, 100], 
  Reverse@Range[9020 - val, val, 100]]), {val, 0, 9000, 100}];
```

You can see the data and the data sampled by `Plot3D` are the same.

```
p2 = ListPointPlot3D[Flatten[res, 1], PlotStyle -> Red]
```

> [image]

**Hint for symmetry!**

```
xval = 9000/2;
yval = 9020 - xval;
pt = {4500, yval, 9020/(9020 + yval)} // N; Show[
Graphics3D[{{Red, Sphere[pt, 3]}, {Red,Sphere[N@First@res[[46]], 3]},
{Blue, Tube[{{xval, xval, 9020/(9020 + xval)}, {xval, 9020 - xval,
 9020/(9020 + (9020 - xval))}}, 1]}}], p1, p2]
```

[image]

Comment: Its giving error as : Wolfram|Alpha doesn't know how to interpret your input

Comment: @Adi [Wolfram|Alpha questions](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/265/52) are specifically off-topic here. However, if you have access to _Mathematica_, then the above code should work fine for you.

Comment: Is there any way to figure the point of symmetry in the above plot .

Comment: @Adi see update!